# May I ask for the reason of downvoting to the voters?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

May I simply know the exact reason of downvoting from the voters? It could be helpful to anyone who is new at this community.

Thanks.

Comment: asdfasdfsdfasdf

Comment: Did that comment help you understand the downvote because that's what you'll get if you make it mandatory?

Comment: I think we should think positive and I hope everyone will not think like this way and won't comment like this also. Its your responsibility to place the reason because you are knowing that the question owner could be a beginner(that is why he is asking such question, for example in a classroom, not everyone understands quickly,isn't it). @ Robert Longson

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman this is how it is here, and it works well. Read the duplicates and see the many many times this has been brought up and rejected by the community.

Comment: And of course one of the reasons you're getting downvotes on this particular question is that you clearly didn't "Read the duplicates and see the many many times this has been brought up and rejected by the community". And we don't need to explain why again because it's right there on the tooltip: This question does not show any research effort...

Comment: "Please read this before making any up or down vote". This usually just results in more downvotes.

Comment: I downvoted here because this question does not show any research effort. (Hope that helps you..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downvoters are not in any way required to make a comment.

Additionally, if you hover over the downvote, you'll see a tool tip explaining a possible reason why. But, realistically, it is not possible to know the exact reason for a downvote (as much as it is impossible to know the exact reason for upvotes either)

Downvotes, like upvotes, are crucial quality controls and should not be taken personally.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your term "as much as it is impossible to know the exact reason for upvotes either", as far as I know there is of-course a valid reason to make upvotes for everyone. well, I think it is not the concern of my question.

Comment: Whatever restrictions that is ever made on downvotes, need to be applied to upvotes - both are quality controls

Comment: I don't think so because it will not be your concern when you are getting upvote however, it will be in case of getting down votes

Comment: The fact is, when a person downvotes, there is no obligation to comment and absolutely no way to enforce any such rule.